# Soul transfer belief

Tags: old-testament, new-testament, words-of-jesus, souls

Does Christianity believe in a soul transfer?

[Soul transfer](https://www.google.com/search?q=soul%20transfer&sca_esv=8b94fdf9c54254b4&sxsrf=ACQVn0-_8h4cHXvWC40T1mhD3qPaHYBkZw%3A1710041260951&source=hp&ei=rCjtZba3N9mc4-EPsbCFgAc&oq=Soul%20transfer&gs_lp=EhFtb2JpbGUtZ3dzLXdpei1ocCINU291bCB0cmFuc2ZlcioCCAAyBRAAGIAEMgUQABiABDIFEAAYgAQyBRAAGIAEMgUQABiABDIFEAAYgAQyBRAAGIAEMgUQABiABEjfRlCkB1iyNHABeACQAQCYAa8CoAGnFaoBBzAuNi42LjG4AQHIAQD4AQGYAg6gAvwYqAIPwgIHECMY6gIYJ8ICBxAuGOoCGCfCAg8QIxiABBiKBRgnGEYY-wHCAgoQIxiABBiKBRgnwgITEC4YgAQYigUYxwEYrwEYjgUYJ8ICChAAGIAEGIoFGEPCAgsQABiABBixAxiDAcICCxAAGIAEGIoFGJECwgIOEC4YgAQYigUYkQIYsQPCAhAQLhiABBiKBRhDGLEDGIMBwgIUEC4YgAQYigUYkQIYsQMYgwEY1ALCAhAQABiABBiKBRhDGLEDGIMBwgINEC4YgAQYigUYQxixA8ICCxAuGIAEGMcBGK8BwgINEAAYgAQYChixAxiDAcICChAuGIAEGIoFGEPCAgcQABiABBgKwgIREC4YgAQYxwEYrwEYmAUYmQWYA2ySBwgwLjMuMTAuMaAHnGI&sclient=mobile-gws-wiz-hp)

Answer (score 0):

No.

The spirit that rightfully and natively inhabits each person's body, his or her own spirit, is not fungible.
The notion of soul transfer contradicts the reality of God's final judgment on each soul. They cannot trade places, since that would undermine the eternal law of justice.

Although spirits of the deceased and perhaps of the unborn may inhabit another person's body during this mortal life, that habitation is temporary and is mutable, and the final state of each soul is determined by God in final judgment. In the end, souls are not transferable, and each person lives his own life to the end of choosing what kind of eternal destiny he will inherit.